# What is the event that XDP socket is attached to?

Tags: module, kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I am developing a kernel module that registers to the receive handler like this:

```c
rx_handler_result_t rxhPacketIn(struct sk_buff **ppkt)
```

However, when I tried to use this kernel module program with XDP program from XDP-tutorial [1](https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/advanced03-AF_XDP), the kernel module was not involved at all, even when I tried to only pass the packets in the XDP kernel program (`return XDP_PASS`). So my question is, how XDP kernel program is attached to the kernel, and does it has higher priority than the kernel module registered as a `rx_handler` ?

Answer (score 0):

The XDP hook with native driver support is before the `sk_buff` allocation. It is therefore before your kernel module on the receive path.

Comment: Do you see any reason why my kernel module was blocked (probably, by the XDP program)  from being activated?